# Pass a variable(value) from the JSON body to the URL in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I would like to pass a particular value as an input to the URI from the JSON body. But i am getting an error as below. Please find below code and expectation is to put the **netid = 12345** in the
place of **netid** in the URL as **{{ api_uri }}/networks/12345/appliance**

**Error:**

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'rules'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/***/firewallrules.yml': line 35, column 10, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n       - name: Firewall rule update\n         ^ here\n"}
```

**URI Task:**

```
- name: Firewall rule update
         uri:
           method: PUT
           url: "{{ api_uri }}/networks/{{ netid(from firewall.json) }}/appliance"
           body: "{{ lookup('file', 'firewall.json') | from_json }}"
           body_format: json
         register: firewallresults
         ignore_errors: yes
```

**Firewall(JSON input to API):**

```
{
    "rules": [
                {
            "comment": "Test1.",
            "destCidr": "x.x.x.x/24",
            "srcCidr": "y.y.y.y/24",
            "netid":"12345"
        },
                        {
            "comment": "Test2",
            "destCidr": "a.a.a.a/24",
            "srcCidr": "b.b.b.b/24",
            "netid":"12345"
        }            ]
}
```

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I have recreated the question with minimal information in it.  I just need a solution to get the netid from my input JSON(Firewall), which will be used in the API URI **{{ netid(from firewall.json) }}** like  uri: {{ api_uri }}/networks/12345/appliance .Kindly help

Comment: The error message reports `AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'rules' ... The error appears to be in '/***/firewallrules.yml'` but I cant find anything about `.rules` or `firewallrules.yml` in your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message reports `AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'rules' ... The error appears to be in '/***/firewallrules.yml'` but I cant find anything about `.rules` or `firewallrules.yml` in your description.

In respect to the minimal information

> I would like to pass a particular value as an input to the URI from the JSON body. ...  need a solution to get the netid from my input JSON ... which will be used in the API URI

it seems that your URI task and URL parameter are misconstructed. I've created a debugging task to get a better understanding of the use case.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    BODY: "{{ lookup('file', 'firewall.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:

  - name: Show BODY
    debug:
      msg: "{{ BODY }}"

  - name: Show first 'netid' for URL
    debug:
      var: BODY.rules[0].netid

  - name: Show all 'netid's for URL
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.netid }}"
    loop: "{{ BODY.rules }}"
```

Resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show first 'netid' for URL] ***
ok: [localhost] =>
  BODY.rules[0].netid: '12345'

TASK [Show all 'netid's for URL] ***
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'comment': u'Test1.', u'destCidr': u'x.x.x.x/24', u'netid': u'12345', u'srcCidr': u'y.y.y.y/24'}) =>
  msg: '12345'
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'comment': u'Test2', u'destCidr': u'a.a.a.a/24', u'netid': u'12345', u'srcCidr': u'b.b.b.b/24'}) =>
  msg: '12345'
```

Comment: Thanks. That was not actually i was looking for, but i got an idea from your solution and i made it work. Thanks again.